# Is it bad for a java application to shutdown while a separate thread is sleeping?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, sleep, shutdown

For example if i have a java command line program that spawns a new thread (thread #2) to do some polling, and then sleep for 5 minutes. while the main thread (thread #1) of the program is running and then finishes before the 5 minutes from thread #2 is up, so the program will exit. Is there any problem with this? Should I interrupt Thread #2 in Thread #1 before the end of the main function in this program?

Comment: The program does not end simply because the main function terminated. All non-daemon threads must terminate for the program to terminate itself normally.

Answer (score 2):

It may be considered bad practice and a sign of poor design by some, but in principal there shouldn't be any problem to terminate the JVM with `System.exit`. Not if there is no clean-up to be performed by Thread #2.

Another issue though, is whether or not Thread #2 may be in the middle of some action.

Comment: Also if a thread can be safely "killed" at any time, it could (or indeed should) be marked as daemon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what it's doing.  When the program exits, the process will terminate, taking any additional threads with it.  The only potential problem would be if Thread #2 holds some resource handle.  However, if all it's doing is reading, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Non-deamon threads keep on running in the background after main has finished execution.
As a result you will have hunging threads unless you **explicitly** call `System.exit` which kills all threads.
The best approach though would be to stop the thread#2.
Just use a status flag e.g. `boolean die` in thread#2.
Thread#1 will interrupt the thread#2, thread#2 will then see the die flag (set by thread#1) set to true, will do any clean up necessary and exit gracefully.
In your case that thread#2 is just sleeping for 5 mins and not doing anything it will be fine.

Comment: Remember to let the die-flag be of type `AtomicBoolean` or at least volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [here](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/shutting_down_threads_cleanly.shtml).

For the termination of a java program, it is necessary for all non-daemon threads to terminate first.
Once all the non-daemon threads stop their execution, the JVM will kill off all the daemon threads and thus will get shut-down.

In you case, there should not be any problem, unless and until your **`Thread #2`** is doing some important function like handling resources.